# Large scale hydroponics and Shmita

Tags: technology, science, agriculture, shmita

The gemara in Nedarim 59 (among many other places) discusses the concept of shmita produce and plants grown from them retaining their status when the original "seed" isn't destroyed when planted. In discussing this point, it brings down that the kedusha of shmita is caused by the land itself. This would imply that objects "not grown in the land itself" would not have shmita upon them even IF they were "grown in Israel."

Nominally, this would exclude things like hydroponics or pot grown vegetables.

However, we also have a halacha that a large enough vessel is considered equivalent to the ground itself, as it comprises an immovable object. As such, a date tree (say) grown in a sufficiently large planter WOULD, in fact, have all the requirements of shmita.

Given that there are concerns in general with hydroponics and their status re: making a bracha, would the "large container" concern still apply to render such produce kodesh lishmita?

Comment: Source for " a halacha that a large enough vessel is considered equivalent to the ground itself, as it comprises an immovable object", please. And even more for "As such, a date tree (say) grown in a sufficiently large planter WOULD, in fact, have all the requirements of shmita".

Comment: @DannySchoemann For the clearest example, look in Kelim for examples of that principal - large enough kelim are considered land, and therefore are not mekabel tumah (much like a house not being mekabel tumah except for tzara'as habayis). Conversely, a TREE planted in a closed pot is STILL considered connected to the ground (Rambam Ma'aser Sheni 10:8, S"A Y"D 296:26) as it will eventually grow through the pot wall. There are also discussions around hothouse planting during shmita that I haven't gotten into here.

Comment: "large enough kelim are considered land, and therefore are not mekabel tumah" would need a source. "Certain large vessels are not mekabel tumah as they are not able to be carried and therefore not like a Sack" is the classic explanation. See keilim 10:1  כֵּלִים גְּדוֹלִים הַבָּאִים בְּמִדָּה שֶׁמַּחֲזִיקִים אַרְבָּעִים סְאָה בְלַח שֶׁהֵן כּוֹרַיִם בְּיָבֵשׁ, דְּלֹא מְקַבְּלֵי טֻמְאָה, דְּבָעִינַן דּוּמְיָא דְשַׂק שֶׁמִּטַּלְטֵל מָלֵא וְרֵיקָן, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁהֵן גְּדוֹלִים כָּל כָּךְ אֵין מִטַּלְטְלִים מְלֵאִים

Comment: As to your Rambam - it says הַנּוֹטֵעַ בְּעָצִיץ שֶׁאֵינוֹ נָקוּב חַיָּב בְּעָרְלָה. אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵינוֹ כְּאֶרֶץ לִזְרָעִים הֲרֵי הוּא כְּאֶרֶץ לְאִילָנוֹת - so sometimes it's not like the ground. Since you're discussing  produce, the שֶׁאֵינוֹ כְּאֶרֶץ לִזְרָעִים would be more relevant.

Comment: As to hothouse planting - that depends on whether a hot house is a house (allowed) or just a covered field. That's how Rav D.A. Morgenstern explained how Rav Elyashiv explained it, IIRC.